# Why i am getting an error when fetching from S3 Bucket url?

Tags: node.js, express, multer, amazon-s3

I tried uploading the image on s3 bucket, image is uploaded successfully but when I fetch the URL, it says "Access Denied".

*PS : I have unchecked *Restrict public access*
[image]

Comment: you need to provide the code you are using to upload and then download the s3 object for us to be able to better help you.  Also, what IAM permissions does your user have and are there any bucket policies on the bucket?  It's possible to grant PutObject but not GetObject permissions which would allow you to upload but not download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this to Bucket Policy solved the problem !!!

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"PublicRead",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject","s3:GetObjectVersion"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::Bucket_Name/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a presigned url. All objects by default are private. Only the object owner has permission to access these objects. However, the object owner can optionally share objects with others by creating a presigned URL, using their own security credentials, to grant time-limited permission to download the objects [1].

You need to create an user with programatic access with the permissions necessary [2].

```js
const S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3');

function async getObject(objectKey) {
  const s3 = new S3({
    accessKeyId: userAwsAccessKey,
    secretAccessKey: userAwsSecretAccessKey,
  });
  
  try {
    // S3 library documentation [3]
    const url = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('getObject', {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: objectKey,
      Expires: 60, // seconds
    });

    return url;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}
```

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_create.html#id_users_create_api

[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrlPromise-property